# unlocking the system preferences is not working

Tags: macos, operating-system, admin, usergroups, system-preferences

System Preferences is trying to unlock users & Groups preferences
Unable to open System preferences for the my MacOs High Sierra.

sudo commands helps to provided the access to unlock the usergroups?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s works after doing this
Restart mac hold 
Ctrl + S

It’s open OS X terminal

mount -uw /

rm /var/db/.ApplesetupDone

reboot

Then follow the instructions to setup for admin

Answer (score 1):

Also had this problem recently, however my account was an admin account, as shown in the Users & Groups pane. `sudo` in the terminal was working correctly, and I could even create new users (admins) using the terminal, however logging in as them would give me the same problem.

[Solution was to reset the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-en/HT201295):

1. Power off the Mac
2. Power on the Mac while holding <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and continue to hold the <kbd>Power</kbd> button for around 10 seconds.
3. Release the buttons and power it on again if it has done it already.

Answer (score 0):

Only admins can change the settings for the Users&Groups. You need to type in your login (username and password) to be able to change the settings. If you are not an admin on this machine, you need to have somebody else who is type in their credentials.

Answer (score 0):

SMC reset worked for me just now (same problem, after upgrading to Big Sur)

Answer (score 0):

Restarting in boot mode and running the following commands should help.
fsck –fy
mount –uw /
rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone
reboot

More details can be found here: https://youtu.be/2NhTlvCjFJI